# There is an island and 20 houses at the beach around the island, each house with 20 wrestlers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, alternative-proof, extremal-combinatorics

There is an island and 20 houses at the beach around the island, each house with 20 wrestlers. Each wrestler fights with all wrestlers from other houses. There is no two wrestlers with the same power and the stronger wrestler always win. We say that house $A$ is stronger than house $B$ if there is $k$ fights in which fighters from house $A$ wins. What is a maximum $k$ if we know that each house is stronger than the neighboring house in the direction of the clock movement?

I was trying to solve this was but in the end I gave up and I read an official solution. I was very unsatisfied how it was solved, because they never say how they find this $k_{\max}$, just proved it is ok. Perhaps someone will have a different aproach here.

Here is an offical solution: http://natjecanja.math.hr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2012_izborno-rjesenja.pdf

Appeared:

- Serbia and Montenegro preparation test for IMO $2006$;
- III International Festival of Young Mathematicians Sozopol $2012$;
- Croatia TST for IMO $2015$;
- Swiss TST for IMO $2018$.

Comment: It looks like a nice generalization of the concept of non-transitive dice - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice

Comment: I suppose you meant "We say that house $A$ is stronger than house $B$ if there are $k$ fights in which fighters from house $A$ win against fighters from house $B$". Is that correct?

Comment: If $k\leq 200$ then it is possible for $A$ to be stronger than $B$ and at the same time $B$ to be stronger than $A$. This means that for any of those lower values of $k$, we can create the clockwise arrangement by simply having every house be stronger than both of its neighbors. Therefore the maximum $k$ is greater than $200$. If $k=400$ then "stronger than" is transitive and it is certainly impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment.

I don’t understand why you are unsatisfied with the official solution. I am for a quarter of a century in math competitions and may assure you that this is a typical solution of (such) a competition problem. It is short, simple and clear. Also it is correct. I provide its English translation for not easy reading Slavic languages people.

> The required number is $k = 290$. Let's first show that $k>290$ is impossible. In every house
>   we rank the wrestlers with respect to their strength (from $1$ to $20$) and choose a wrestler who is tenth by strength in each house. Let the weakest among the chosen wrestlers live in the house $A$. Then in
>   every other house $B$ (and, in particular, in the house neighbor to house $A$) there are at least $10$ wrestlers
>   (from 1st to 10th strength rank) who beat at least $11$ wrestlers (from 10th to 20th strength rank)
>   from $A$. So the number of fights in which the wrestlers from $A$ beat wrestlers from its neighbor house  is at most $20\cdot 20 – 10\cdot 11 = 290$, which is a contradiction with the assumption that house $A$ is stronger than its neighbor.
>
> An example that shows that for $k = 290$ the cyclic house strength order is possible can be constructed as 
>   follows. Rank all $400$ wrestlers from the weakest to the strongest, and we mark
>   $210$ weaker (for $1$ to $210$) and $190$ stronger wrestlers (from $211$ to $400$). For each $i = 1, \dots, 20$, let's
>   in the house $A_i$ live $i$ weaker and $20-i$ and stronger wrestlers. More precisely, in $A_1$ live wrestlers with ranks $1$ and from $211$ to $229$, in $A_2$ live wrestlers with ranks $2$, $3$ and form $230$ to $247$ etc.
>
> Let us show that the house $A_i$ is stronger than the house $A_{i-1}$ for each $i = 2,\dots 20$. All the weaker wrestlers from $A_i$ beat the weaker wrestlers from $A_{i-1}$, and all the stronger wrestlers from $A_i$ beat all wrestlers from $A_{i-1}$. The number the fights in which the wrestlers from the house $A_i$ win is $i(i-1) + (20-i)20 = i^2-21i + 400$. This number is the smallest when $i = 10$ or $i = 11$ and then it is exactly 290. In addition, $19$  stronger wrestlers from the house $A_1$ beat all the wrestlers from the house $A_{20}$, so there were $20\cdot 19 = 380>290$ victories and the house $A_1$ is stronger than the house $A_{20}$, which proves the claim.

Comment: Well there is not explained how did they get this 290. They just prove that 290 is OK but there is no methodological way to find this number. So, my question is how would someone find this 290.

Comment: @JohnWatson I also don’t see a clear way to this number. I guess that both participants and jury of IMO selection have a common belief that the first should be sufficiently smart to find lower and upper bounds which are good up to coincidence. :-)

Comment: Even when you were writing this comment I have encountered the same problem with an [other contest math bounty question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474654/find-the-least-of-the-lambda-such-this-inequality-hold), about which OP have told  “I have heard my country's there are no people who solved this problem”. :-) Let’s wait what other MSE members will say.

Comment: @JohnWatson I do agree with you, this expectation of coming up with solutions by "divine inspiration" is one of the things that turned me off math contests in school in favour of physics. But this one's not that bad. I started looking at 3 houses, 3 wrestlers each, and that gave me the idea of how to construct the example which shows some $k$ works. I think you could get to 290 then by seeing how far you can push that construction. For me it turned out trickier to prove that 291 can't be done some other way - now that I read this solution, I'm embarrassed by the simplicity of that part.