# Find the least of the $\lambda$ such this inequality hold?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Give postive integer  $n$,  find the least real numbers $\lambda$, and $0<a_{i}<2^i,\forall i=1,2,\cdots,n$. have
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\{a_{i}a_{j}\}\le \lambda  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\{a_{i}\}$$ where $\{x\}=x-[x]$.

This inequality I have try sometimes,and I can't solve it. and I  have heard my country's There are  no people who solved this problem

Now it is said the answer is
$$\lambda_{\min}=2^{n+1}-n-2+\dfrac{n+(2^{n+1}-n-2)(2^n-1)}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}}$$

Comment: Have you tried some small examples, say $n = 1$ or $2$?

Comment: which country is it?

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\{a_{i}a_{j}\} = \lambda\left({\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{a_{i}\}}\right)^2$$ where $\{x\}=x-[x]$.  If you denote $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\{a_{i}\}$., Then the inequality reduces to  $0\le f(x)\le \lambda$ Then $\lambda$'s least value is $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} -  \sum_{i=1}^{n}[a_{i}] = 2^n - 1 - n$

Comment: for instance when $n=1$, $\lambda = 1+\sqrt{2} \approx 2.4142$, meaning that $0 < a_1 <2$ then ${a_1^2} \leq (1+\sqrt{2}) {a_1}$, is this what you are asking for, the minimum value for $\lambda$ which is valid for all $a_1,\cdots ,a_n$?

Answer (score 3):

**Update : Full Answer**

Let $a_n = \sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}$ , $a_i = \frac{(2^i-1)(2^n-1)+1}{a_n}$ for all $1 \leq i <n$.

Then $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \{a_i \} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \{\frac{(2^i-1)(2^n-1)+1}{a_n}\}  + \{a_n\} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{(2^i-1)(2^n-1)+1}{a_n}-(2^i-1) + a_{n}-2^n+1 =\frac{\left(a_n-2^n+2\right) \left(a_n-2^n+n\right)}{a_n} $,

On the other-hand we have that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \{a_i a_j\} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i^2\} +2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-2} \sum \limits_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \{a_i a_j\} + 2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \{a_i a_n\}$,

We know that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \{a_i a_n\} =1$,since $a_i = \frac{integer}{a_n}$,so $2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \{a_i a_n\}=2(n-1)$.

Also $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \{ a_n^2 \} =1$ so we have $2n-1 + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \{a_i^2\} +2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-2} \sum \limits_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \{a_i a_j\} $

$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \{a_i^2\} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{((2^i-1)(2^n-1)+1)^2}{a_n^2} - \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} (2^i-1)^2 = \frac{\left(2^n-2\right) \left(-6 n+8^n-3\ 2^{2 n+1}+3\ 2^n (n+4)-4\right)-a_n^2
   \left(3 n+4^n-3\ 2^{n+1}+5\right)}{3 a_n^2}$, and

$ 2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-2} \sum \limits_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \{a_i a_j\} = 2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-2} \sum \limits_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \frac{((2^i-1)(2^n-1)+1)((2^j-1)(2^n-1)+1)}{a_n^2} -(2^i-1)(2^j-1) = \frac{\left(2^n-2\right) \left(2 \left(-3\ 2^{n+1}+8^n+2\right)-3
   \left(2^n-2\right) \left(-n+2^{n+1}+1\right) n\right)-a_n^2 \left(2
   \left(4^n-1\right)+3 n \left(n-2^{n+1}+1\right)\right)}{3 a_n^2}$

so $\lambda \geq \frac{\left(2^n-2\right)^2 \left(2^n-n\right)^2-a^2 \left(n^2+4^n-2^{n+1} (n+1)+2\right)}{a \left(a-2^n+2\right) \left(a-2^n+n\right)}$ , so $\lambda \geq 4*2^n-2n-4$ (i proved it, not easy to prove but anyone could check and see this is true for all integers,see Alex's result about this lower bound), and this becomes more and more accurate as $n \to \infty$.

Now we will prove the upper bound,

we have one of the 2 cases :

1) there is $i$ such that $\{ a_i \} \geq \frac{1}{n^2}$ or 2) for all $i$ we have $\{a_i \} < \frac{1}{n^2}$

in the first case we know that $ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{ a_i \} \geq \frac{1}{n^2}$ and that $ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \{a_i a_j\} \leq n^2$ so $\lambda \leq \frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = n^4$.

in the second case we get that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \{a_i a_j \} = \{ (\{a_i \} +[a_i]) (\{a_j\}+[a_j]) \} = \{ [a_i][a_j] + [a_j]\{a_i\} + [a_i] \{a_j\} + \{a_i \} \{a_j \} \}  \leq \{ (2^j-1)\{a_i\}+ (2^i-1) \{a_j\} +\{a_i \} \{a_j \} \} = 2 \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} (2^j-1) + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \{a_i \} \{a_j \} = (4*2^n-2n-4) \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i \} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \{a_i \} \{a_j \} \leq  (4*2^n-2n-4) \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i \}+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i\} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2} = (4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n}) \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i \}$

So $(4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n}) \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i \} \geq \lambda \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \{a_i \} $ so $(4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n}) \geq \lambda $

So we are left with $ 4*2^n-2n-4 \leq \lambda \leq max(n^4,4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n})$

And its true that $4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n} > n^4 $ for all $n>12$,

So for all integers $n >12$ we have that $4*2^n-2n-4 \leq \lambda \leq 4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n}$, (for smaller cases one could prove that its also holds true but not easy).

Thus completing the proof and $4*2^n-2n-4 \leq \lambda \leq 4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n} $ or $\lambda = 4*2^n-2n-4+O(\frac{1}{n})$.

**Update by Alex Ravsky**. Your idea is good. I came to a similar idea yesterday,  but I had no Internet connection first and had to go to my university later. I am still trying to improve it. Your idea can be developed as follows. Put $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{a_i\}$. If $S\le \lambda –2^{n+2}+2n+4$ then my upper bound works. If  $S\ge \lambda –2^{n+2}+2n+4$ then it suffices to have $\lambda (\lambda –2^{n+2}+2n+4)\ge n^2$, that is we can put $$\lambda=2^{n+1}-n-2+\sqrt{(2^{n+1}-n-2)^2+n^2}\le 2^{n+2}-2n-4+\frac{n^2}{2^{n+1}-2n-4}.$$

On the other hand, $$\lambda_{\min}-2^{n+2}+2n+4=
\frac{n+(2^{n+1}-n-2)(2^n-1)}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}}-2^{n+1}-n-2=$$

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}}+\varepsilon_n,$$ where

$$|\varepsilon_n|=
 (2^{n+1}-n-2) \left|\frac{2^n-1}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}}-1\right|\le $$

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n-1}\left|2^n-1-\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}\right|=$$

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n-1}\left|\frac{(2^n-1)^2-(\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1})^2}{2^n-1+\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}}\right|\le $$

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n-1}\left|\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-2}\right|=O\left(\frac 1{2^n}\right).$$

Similarly, for my lower bound the difference is

$n(\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}-(2^n-1))= n\frac{
\left(\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}\right)^2-(2^n-1)^2}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}+2^n-1}=
\frac{n}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}+2^n-1}\le \frac{n}{2^{n+1}-2}.$

The following graph represents the current bounds state, where values of $f(n)$ for each funtion $f$ is drawn as $(f(n)-2^{n+2}+2n+4)\frac {2^n}n$. Legend: red - $\lambda_{min}$, green – current best upper bound, blue - my lower bound.

[image]

Comment: $a_ia_n$ is an integer for each $i$, thus  $\{a_ia_n\}=0$. It seems that in order to make them close to $1$ we have to make all $a_i$’s (including $a_n$) a bit less.

Comment: If $[a_ia_j]=(2^i-1)(2^j-1)$ (which seems to be true, but is not proved in your answer) then it seems than you can more simply and clearly evaluate $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n-1}\{a_ia_j\}=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n-1} a_ia_j-(2^i-1)(2^j-1)$ directly than splitting it into other sums, as you do it now.

Comment: It is hard to check your calculations, because many intermediate steps are missed (for instance, why the final complicated lower bound for $\lambda$ implies $\lambda\ge 2^{n+2}-2n-4$? Althoug I have a calculation evidednce that this is true, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO6hR.png) graph (I have guessed that $a$ is $a_n$). This is OK beacuse they are routine, but now the problem is a matter of precision.

Comment: As a resume I can say that your idea look promising. Nevertheless, there still remains a gap of size $n$ between the upper and the lower bound for improvement.

Comment: @AlexRavsky all what you said in the comments is correct, i did say that i have no proof, but highly suspect that $ \lambda = 4*2^n-2n-4 +\epsilon$ and when $n \to \infty$ then $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky so the lower bound is strict, so you or i need to lower the upper bound to make it $4*2^n-2n- A$ for some constant $A$, i think a better walk through your argument and mine  we could lower the upper bound to the desired approximation and then we will know that $\lambda = 4*2^n-2n+O(1)$.

Comment: I have reduced the proof of the lower bound, see my updated answer.

Comment: I have reduced the proof of the upper bound too.

Comment: @AlexRavsky could you please, check my proof.

Comment: can you prove this $\lambda $ is $\lambda_{\min}=2^{n+1}-n-2+\dfrac{n+(2^{n+1}-n-2)(2^n-1)}{\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}}$？

Comment: @communnites i said before that this seems to be $\lambda_{min}$ but such proof is beyond my ability but, now we know that $4*2^n-2n-4 \leq \lambda_{min} \leq 4*2^n-2n-4+\frac{1}{n}$, so its "good bounds", maybe Alex could complete the last step in the proof.

Comment: @communnites Mathcad checked that Ahmad’s lower bound is indeed $\lambda_{min}$. I have to go to the university soon, so I vote to award Ahmad by the bounty for his deep insight.

Answer (score 2):

I can prove that the least required $\lambda$ belongs to the interval  $$\left[2^{n+2}-2n-4+n(\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}-(2^n-1)),2^{n+2}-n-4\right].$$

Given numbers $0<a_{i}<2^i$, for each $i$ and $j$ we have 
$$\{a_{i}a_{j}\}=\{([a_i]+\{a_i\})([a_j]+\{a_j\}) \}=$$
$$\{[a_i][a_j]+[a_i]\{a_j\}+[a_j]\{a_i\}+\{a_i\}\{a_j\}\}=$$
$$\{[a_i]\{a_j\}+[a_j]\{a_i\}+\{a_i\}\{a_j\}\}\le $$

$$\{[a_i]\{a_j\}\}+\{[a_j]\{a_i\}\}+\{\{a_i\}\{a_j\}\}\le $$

$$ (2^i-1)\{a_j\}+(2^j-1)\{a_i\}+\{a_i\}\{a_j\}.$$

Put $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{a_i\}$. We have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\{a_{i}a_{j}\}\le 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2^i-1)\{a_j\}+(2^j-1)\{a_i\}+\{a_i\}\{a_j\}=$$ 
$$2S\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2^j-1)+S^2=(2^{n+2}-2n-4)S+S^2\le(2^{n+2}-n-4)S.$$

Thus $\lambda\le 2^{n+2}-n-4$.

On the other hand, given $n$, pick a positive $\varepsilon$ such that $(2^{n+1}-2)\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2<1$ and put $a_i=2^i-1+\varepsilon$ for each $i$. Then $\{a_i\}=\varepsilon$ and $\{a_ia_j\}=(2^i+2^j-2)\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2$. We can easily caclulate that the left hand side of the inequality equals $(n2^{n+2}-2n^2-4n)\varepsilon+n^2\varepsilon^2$ and the left hand side equals $n\lambda\varepsilon$, so  $\lambda\ge 2^{n+2}-2n-4+n\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}-(2^n-1)$, we have $\lambda\ge 2^{n+2}-2n-4+n(\sqrt{(2^n-1)^2+1}-(2^n-1)).$

Comment: Now, its very good.